# How to remove space between border and inner content?

Tags: html, css

This is from Firefox, and there is no space
[image: image1]
This is from Android Chrome, and there is no space
[image: image2]
And this is from Chrome, and there is space
[image: image3]

Here is the white space
i have added green color section code and white box code also

```css
.details section:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

and below is the CSS code

```css
.channel {
    border: 1px solid rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.8);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 266px;
    width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the gap is 2px.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to set the padding to 0px as it is what (should) define the space between the inner content and the border as you can see here when you hit F12 (at least on firefox).
[image: view of the margin border and padding of an item]

You could do it by adding the following line to your CSS code:

```
padding: 0px;
```